# What is the standard page of '.plist'?

Tags: ios, plist

I'm new in iOS.

and Now, I'm trying to distribute .ipa using .plist in IIS.

So, I put on the .plist file in IIS, open the .plist ('http://myIP/app.plist')

When I use Safari, I got just plain text. like 'items asset kind software-package .... '

But, when I use chrome, I got xml( 
< plist version="1.0" > ... ).

**What is standard page of .plist ??
just plain text? or xml ?**

I think Safari open the .plist file like plain-text, but It is wrong..

I'm confusing about it... Give me the hint. Thanks

and,

**+ Should I set 'https' in the .ipa path?** (When I use http:~~, I got some error about certificates.)

p.s>

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>    
< !DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">    
< plist version="1.0">    
< dict>    
        < key>items</key>   
        < array>   
                < dict>  
                        < key>assets</key>   
                        < array>
                                < dict>   
                                        < key>kind</key>
                                        < string>software-package</string>
                                        < key>url</key>
                                        < string>[INSERT URL HERE]</string>
                                < /dict>
                        < /array>
                        < key>metadata</key>
                        < dict>
                                < key>bundle-identifier</key>
                                < string>[INSERT BUNDLE ID HERE]</string>
                                < key>bundle-version</key>
                                < string>[INSERT VERSION HERE]</string>
                                < key>kind</key>
                                < string>software</string>
                                < key>title</key>
                                < string>[INSERT APP TITLE HERE]</string>
                        < /dict>
                < /dict>
        < /array>
< /dict>
< /plist>
```

Answer (score 0):

I open a .plist file by Chrome and get this info : **This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.**

It is a xml file , and the .storyboard and .xib files are also xml. You can open them in the Xcode , right click on the .plist file , choose  **Open as** -> **Source code** , then it will show as a xml file.

And Safari cannot open it ...

Http will be deprecated in the future by iOS , we need to be ready for it.
Thats what i can help .

Comment: Safari can not open the .plist as an 'xml' form??
I mean... When I open .plist as an safari, I got just plain-text. but other's .plist is shown as an xml file.... It is the reason why I'm confusing...

Comment: Yes , on my mac my safari cannot open the plist file. May be your plist file is not create by Xcode ? So this plist file lacks some header code ?

Comment: yep. I just make use the '.text' file.
I added the referenced plist  (edited my question.).